# Emacs installer for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, emacs

As of the 1st of April 2013 (and no, this is not an April Fool prank) the [Emacs Windows FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Introduction.html#Introduction) states that

```
Emacs 23.3 is known to run on all versions of Windows from Windows 95 and Windows NT 4.0 through to Vista.
```

Are there any approved Emacs installers (i.e. not self-build) tried and tested on Windows 8?

Comment: If it works on Windows Vista then it already works on Windows 8.  As for the reason Windows 7 or Windows 8 is not listed its because nobody bothered to update the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are native Windows builds of FSF Emacs at ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/ (e.g., `emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip`). Just extract the ZIP file wherever you prefer, and create a shortcut to `bin\runemacs.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [EmacsW32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html). While I tend to prefer running Emacs under Cygwin, I have used the EmacsW32 install in the past, and it worked well enough.