# /usr/local or /opt on Windows

Tags: windows, file-organization

On Linux systems, you have directory trees like /usr/local or /opt where you can put "custom-installed" applications which don't have a package in your distribution and, thus, do not fit nicely into your distribution's FHS.

On Windows, where do you put applications which do not provide an installer, and, thus, do not split themselves nicely into `C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\ProgramData`? Is there a well-established convention?

---

*Background:* Many small tools (e.g. the sysinternals tools) or Unix-ported applications (e.g. emacs) do not provide a Windows installer but rather a zip file with the instruction to "[just extract it anywhere and start the exe file](https://superuser.com/a/576418/14517)". Now, I *could* create an arbitrary top-level directory, e.g. `C:\Tools`, but, being pedantic, I'd like it to have the "right" name. Is there some consensus or does everyone invent his/her own convention for this type of application?

Comment: I make a directory called C:\bin and add the it to the system path environmental variable, then dump my executables there. Windows has no real provisions for this type of "installation". You could just as easily make it in C\Program Files (x86)\bin or anywhere else you like, there is no standard for it.

Answer (score 3):

As I often have the same small tools at home and at work, and because usually companies do not let users have admin privileges, installing in e.g. `C:\tools` or even `"C:\Program Files\Tools"` is not an option. In order to keep my install scripts the same, I use a root junction which points to my user directory. That junction requires admin privileges but it's a one shot:

```
C:\>mkdir %USERPROFILE%\localapp
C:\>mklink /J localapp %USERPROFILE%\localapp
```

Then you can provide `C:\localapp` to MSI installers of portable tools or unzip tools there, even without privileges, and use that in the PATH. I have for example the same at home and at work:

```
C:\localapp\Mozilla
C:\localapp\Sysinternals
C:\localapp\Joeware
...
```

Up to a certain extent (like the fact that the junction may not exist), it also allows you to have the same tools on all computers if using a roaming profile.

You could as well install in `C:\Users\yourself\localapp` directly but in my case my user name is not the same everywhere, and `%USERPROFILE%` can't always be used unexpanded (e.g. in registry) so it's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

No fast rule regarding this.

Suggestion: Go with `c:\tools`, *or `c:\opt` if you are more familiar with linux.*

You might have to change permissions on this new folder as some apps will require elevated permissions to write their own data here.

As developer I'm using this structure:

```
C:\
+-- code  // for repositories   
+-- data  // db files  
+-- tools // software tools
```

This makes it easy for me to keep track of the tools I'm using and their configurations when setting up a new dev environment on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has an `AppData` directory of any user in which the user has full privileges and that some installers use to install their application without the need of privileged access. However, since `/usr/local` is a directory for all normal users, you should find the equivalent of the users `AddData` folder for all users.

The all-users profile (`C:\Users\All Users`)  is just a symlink to `C:\ProgramData` and it does not contain an `AppData` folder, but it seems to be the `AppData` folder for all users.

The folks behind [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) decided to install Chocolatey to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey`, so I guess it is safe to conclude that the equivalent of `/usr/local` (as well as `/var` or `/etc`) is `C:\ProgramData\` which is stored in and expanded from `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` and `%PROGRAMDATA%`. In prior versions `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` was hidden in the Windows folder.

So, you should prefer to use `%PROGRAMDATA%` for system-wide binaries and configurations that are shared between all users. This is your "GlobalAppData" directory.

For user-specific binaries or configurations there is `%LOCALAPPDATA%`.